# AspNetBoilerplate: Scaffolding for multiple APIs sharing underlying framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

We are building multiple APIs using ASP Net Boilerplate. I already managed to create a single authentication server for all of them with IdentityServer4, and now I'm trying to create a single solution for all of the applications, with different Web.Host projects to launch the APIs, that share the base Boilerplate framework and other classes to reuse code and minimize duplication.

Is there any example or tutorial regarding this? This is the first time trying something like this and I'm finding it difficult to understand how to separate and scaffold everything.

This is basicaly my idea and what I have so far:

[image]

Comment: Whilst you can do this, I would guess that the scaffolding won't work because it doesn't expect this pattern.   Either 1) create a different solution for each API, but include the same .csproj files for the shared code, or 2) create nuget packages for the shared code and include them in the solution.   Option 1 will be easier to debug and maintain.